# Can chrome step over lines?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, breakpoints, devtools

Consider this code

```
debugger;

const {a,b,c,d,e}={a:3,b:4,c:5,d:6,e:7};
const assignmentOfInterest=myfunc();
const {a2,b2,c2,d2,e2}={a2:3,b2:4,c2:5,d2:6,e2:7};
const assignmentOfInterest2=myfunc();
const {a3,b3,c3,d3,e3}={a3:3,b3:4,c3:5,d3:6,e3:7};
const assignmentOfInterest2=myfunc();
// etc
```

Pressing F10 ("step over", yes **not** "step into"!) multiple times does not get me very far .. at all. Actually a waste of time.

With a line like const {a,b,c,d,e}={a:3,b:4,c:5,d:6,e:7} you have to "step over" **five** times in order to go to the next line. Only applies to chrome, firefox does this just fine it seems.

***I need a "continue to next line" keyboard shortcut.***

I **know** there is a "continue to here" option. But that's not really convenient having to alternate between "step over" an "continue to here". *I just want to use the keyboard.*

Chrome newest version 81. Vannila JS, NO transpiler used

Comment: Are you clicking step *into*? AFAIK, step over in Chrome just executes the entire line not individual parts.

Comment: "Step over next function call" (F10) double checked right now. chrome is up to date version 81. no sourcemaps involved. vanilla JS.

Comment: OK, I tried it myself - you're right, for `const {a,b,c,d,e}={a:3,b:4,c:5,d:6,e:7};` it goes over `a`, then `b`, then `c`, then `d`, then `e`. I've not used Chrome for debugging enough, it seems, I hadn't run into this until now.

Comment: i just cant believe this is intended. why would it. and no dev in the world has stumbled upon this yet? JS is not that unpopular. but found nothing on the web about it, thus this post. maybe i missed a secret chrome flag to configure "step over" functionality

Comment: "Step over" does not mean *"skip next instruction"*. It just means roughly "do not further drill into the current statement and just execute it." I don't think the debugger has any option to *not execute* selected code.

Comment: @deceze the idea is that with a line like `const {a, b, c} = {a:1, b:2, c:3}` you have to "step over" *three times* in order to go to the next line. It goes through each one of the assignments - `a`, `b`, and `c`. With FF doing step over, directly does all assignments and goes to the next line. Open the dev tools and try [here](https://jsbin.com/yanidaqusi/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: If there is the option for me to rightclick on the next line and select "continue to here" that is the proof that chrome devs can program that into chrome via keyboard shortcut. An algorithm that says "find next line" is not impossible. just search for next line break.

Comment: I see what you're saying now, that was very unclear from the description…